# Ito's Formula for functions that are $C^2$ almost everywhere

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

In the conventional Ito's formula, it is required that $F$ is $C^2$ everywhere. However I've seen mentioning of a slightly weaker condition, where $F$ is $C^1$ everywhere but $C^2$ *almost* everywhere. Is there any reference for this? I couldn't find it in the textbooks by Oksendal or Protter.

Comment: I did not look into it, but the title of [R. Aebi, *Itô's Formula for Non-Smooth Functions*, Publ. RIMS, Kyoto Univ. 28 (1992), 595-602] ([link](https://www.ems-ph.org/journals/show_pdf.php?issn=0034-5318&vol=28&iss=4&rank=5)) suggests it may contain an answer.

Comment: Also, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2521208/other-versions-of-a-weak-ito-formula) at Math.SE.

Answer (score 1):

There is a comment to this effect in Revuz and Yor's *Continuous Martingales and Brownian Motion* after the proof for continuous semimartingale vector $X=(X^1,\dots,X^d)$ and $F\in C^2$ (pg 147):

> **Remark 1°)** The differentiability properties of $F$ may be somewhat relaxed. For instance, if some of the $X^{i}$'s are of finite variation, $F$ needs only be of class $C^1$ in the corresponding coordinates; the proof goes through just the same.